# Iterate through all objects that have been encoded using NSCoding iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class (SpendrList) that has an `NSMutableArray` property that acts a list that the user saves multiple things to while using an app (it's a datasource for a `UITableView`). Using the `NSCoding` protocol, I encode/decode this class as needed.

This works fine, as the array property holds list items from a class I created, SpendrListItem, (also adhering to `NSCopying` protocol) and I encode it as the user makes any edit in the `UITableView`, like so:

```
NSURL *dataFile = [FileSystemHelper pathForDocumentsFile:kFilePathList];
NSString *filePath = [dataFile path];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:_list toFile:filePath];
```

Right now, I am just dealing with one list so this was relatively easy to set up after a few tutorials on NSCoding. Now, what I want to do is code in support for the user to have *multiple lists* in my app.

I have a collection view in another ViewController set up where I want to display all the lists created, and **I am wondering if I can iterate through all objects I have encoded contained in the app sandbox**.

Psuedocode:

```
for (encodedObject in App Sandbox){
  if([encodedObject isTypeOfClass: SpendrList]){
     //Add to iVar array to show in collection view 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Multiple Lists [in isolation]*?

Sounds like documents.  Specifically, if you have multiple chunks of data that are held in relative isolation, even if identical in structure, you should likely manage and persist them separately.   Potentially, you might have a master document that keeps track of the inventories of other documents.

That is, persist those lists to separate files.

Fortunately, iOS has an entire infrastructure for helping you with this;  see [UIDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html).